# Ruby partial block render out of order

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, haml

I am defining a block in a template and passing that into a partial and rendering it to a string but calling the block inside the partial appears to render into the template context?

**lib/test.rb**

```
class Test
  def render(&block)
    view = ApplicationController.new()

    view.class_eval do
      include ApplicationHelper
    end

    view.render_to_string(:partial => 'cool_partial', :locals => {
      :block   => block
    })

  end
end
```

**controller/action.haml**

```
= @test_obj.render do |variable|
  %td='hello-world'
```

**app/view/_cool_partial.haml**

```
%table
  %tr
    (0..5).each do |i|
       block.call
```

**Output**

```
<td>hello-world</td>
<td>hello-world</td>
<td>hello-world</td>
<td>hello-world</td>
<td>hello-world</td>
<table>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually due to an issue inside HAML:
http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/Haml/Engine.html

> Due to some Ruby quirks, if scope is a Binding or Proc object and a block is given, the evaluation context may not be quite what the user expects.

However, this can be worked around with the `capture_haml` helper!

```
= capture_haml &row_block
```

You can still pass params too, with

```
= capture_haml arg1, arg2, &row_block
```